# Checking if files exist in folders

Tags: powershell

I have a task to monitor if files exist in certain folders for longer then 5 minutes.  I need the script to only send emails if files exist older then 5 minutes.  Right now the script will run and email me however I am having trouble getting the output formatted correctly.

I'd like the email to include the first column of the CSV, Company, the path and the output of get-childitem.  I will be removing the write-host's  since the script will run via a scheduled task. The CSV has the following format..

```
\\some\share
\\some\share2
\\some\share3
```

Though I would like to have it as..

```
Company1,\\some\share
Company2,\\some\share2
Company3,\\some\share3
```

So that I can include the first header in the email

Here's what I have for the code so far..

```
$SmtpClient = new-object system.net.mail.smtpClient 
$MailMessage = New-Object system.net.mail.mailmessage 

$SmtpClient.Host = "smtp.some.address" 
$MailMessage.from = ($ServerName + "@someaddress.com") 
$MailMessage.To.add("me@someaddress.com")  
$MailMessage.Subject = "File Monitor" 

$date = (get-date).AddMinutes(-5)
foreach($path in get-content "C:\Scripts\servers_path.txt") {
   if ((Test-Path -path $path)) {
    $item = get-childitem $path *.* | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $date}
    $item | Select FullName, Name, LastWriteTime
    if ($item) {
        $MailMessage.Body += "$path `n"
        $MailMessage.Body += "$item `n`n"
        $MailMessage.Body += "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------`n" 
    }
}
    elseif (!(Test-Path $path)) {
    Write-Host "The folder," $path "does not exist" -fore red
    }
    }
    $SmtpClient.Send($MailMessage)
```

Thank you

Comment: So is formatting of the output not necessarily "Checking if files exist in folders" right? Also where is the company property?

Comment: Not sure what you mean regarding the output.. The company property would be in the CSV with this format.. 

    Company1,\\some\share
    Company2,\\some\share2
    Company3,\\some\share3

Comment: I think @CalebB is asking how do you decide what "Company" is? Are you populating this manually?

Comment: Ahh, the company would be in the csv along with the path in the second example in the original post.  Company,Path so on.  Yes, this would be populated manually since folders would get added, removed at anytime.

Comment: I don't see any reference to company in the second example? Are you adding this manually? Is it somehow in servers_path.txt? Is it coming from the same place that `$path` is?

Comment: Hmm thats wierd, It's in the second block of code.  But anyway, yes I would add the entries manually though that is not really important.  Yep it would be in servers_path.txt, again in the format: Company1,\\unc\share1 etc

Comment: If it is part of `servers_path.txt` then `Test-Path -path $path` should fail since `Company1,\\unc\share1` is not a valid path. Yes, it could be a trivial component of this question but the data you are working with is unclear to me and other from what I can see. Is servers_path.txt acutally a CSV file in itself? Wait... the file format in the second example is the sample data you want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think originally I was confusing your input as output in the question. How about something like this then? Assuming the following input data is contained in `"c:\temp\data.txt"`.

```
Company1,\\some\share
Company2,\\some\share2
Company3,\\some\share3
```

Read the comments in code to get a sense for what is going on there. This code would go in place of your `ForEach` loop that you already have in theory. You would need to play with the output to get your desired outcome. If I am off base be as verbose as possible.

```powershell
$date = (get-date).AddMinutes(-5)
# Import the data as a csv into PowerShell specifying the headers since they dont exist.
Import-csv -Path "c:\temp\data.txt" -Header "Company","Path" | ForEach-Object{
    # Check if the path is valid for this item. 
    If(Test-Path $_.Path){
        # This folder exists. Check the contents for certain files. 
        $data = Get-ChildItem $_.Path | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $date}
        If($data){
            # Output the company name and path on a separate line. 
            $message = "`r`n$($_.Company)`r`n$($_.Path)`r`n"
            # Output each file on its own line. 
            $message += "$(($data | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name) -Join "`r`n")"
            # Append built string to the body of the email. 
            $MailMessage.Body += $message
        }
    } Else {
        # Path does not exist. Have message stating such.
        $MailMessage.Body += "`r`n$($_.Company)`r`n$($_.Path) does not exist `r`n"
    }
}
```

If you wanted to return more properties like `LastWriteTime` we could do that if we replace this one line

```
$message += "$(($data | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name) -Join "`r`n")"
```

With something like this:

```
$data | ForEach-Object{
    $message += "Name: '{0}' - Last Write Time: '{1}'" -f $_.Name, $_.LastWriteTime
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, that worked great.  I think the last thing I'd like to do is at Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name, I would want the LastWriteTime.  I't seems the -ExpandProperty can only select one column?

Comment: `-ExpandProperty` will take one parameter to return an array of strings as supposed to a object array that contains one parameter. Can easily change it though.